# object to xml is not generated correctly by java in case of multiple objects

Tags: java, xstream

As shown below, I have a POJO class with setters and getters:

```
public class InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage  {
    private String InvoiceReference;
    private String ABSReference;
    private String Currency;
    private double InvoiceAmount;
    private double PaidAmount;
    private double BalanceAmount;
    private Date ValueDate;
    private String Remarks;
}
```

and below is the class in which the above is being referenced:

```
public class Mail {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private  InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage;

    public InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage getInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage() {
        return invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage;
    }

    public void setInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage(
            InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage) {
        this.invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage = invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage;
    }
}
```

I am using xstream to generate the xml from the object. I have no problem creating a single object in java as shown below:

```
public class InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessagetest {

    InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage = new InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage();
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setInvoiceReference("S15");
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setABSReference("IRMA1");
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setCurrency("GBP");
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setInvoiceAmount(25746);
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setPaidAmount(18245);
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setBalanceAmount(90);
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setValueDate(new Date());
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage.setRemarks("abc");


    Mail m = new Mail();
    m.setInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage);
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.alias("brokermail",Mail.class);
    String abc = xstream.toXML(m);
}
```

The tags which I finally get is as shown below:

```xml
<brokermail>
  <invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
    <InvoiceReference>dffg</InvoiceReference>
    <ABSReference>Ifgfg</ABSReference>
    <Currency>Ggfg</Currency>
    <InvoiceAmount>2554546.0</InvoiceAmount>
    <PaidAmount>125445.0</PaidAmount>
    <BalanceAmount>0454.0</BalanceAmount>
    <ValueDate>2015-:34.165 IST</ValueDate>
    <Remarks>abc</Remarks>
  </invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
   <invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
    <InvoiceReference>xxRRR5</InvoiceReference>
    <ABSReference>IRMAR15657311</ABSReference>
    <Currency>EUR</Currency>
    <InvoiceAmount>2545446.0</InvoiceAmount>
    <PaidAmount>154245.0</PaidAmount>
    <BalanceAmount>045.0</BalanceAmount>
    <ValueDate>2015-05-20 21:34:34.165 IST</ValueDate>
    <Remarks>abffc</Remarks>
  </invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
</brokermail>
```

but I have changed my mail class to store multiple objects in below fashion

```
public class Mail {
    private  List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage = new ArrayList<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>();

    public List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> getInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessages() {
        return invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage;
    }

    public void addInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessages(List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> invoiceReferenceNotificationMessages) {
        this.invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage = invoiceReferenceNotificationMessages;
    }
}
```

now when I am creating the objects as shown below..

```
List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest = new ArrayList<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>();
        invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest.add(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage);
        invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest.add(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1);

        Mail m = new Mail();
        m.addInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessages(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest);

XStream xstream = new XStream();
        xstream.alias("brokermail",Mail.class);
        String abc = xstream.toXML(m);
```

I am getting the tag as shown below:

```xml
<brokermail>
  <invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
    <com.jms.InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
      <InvoiceReference>SM/829743434309/0315</InvoiceReference>
      <RBSReference>IRMAR34343157311</RBSReference>
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <InvoiceAmount>23434546.0</InvoiceAmount>
      <PaidAmount>124345.0</PaidAmount>
      <BalanceAmount>0.0</BalanceAmount>
      <ValueDate>2015-05-21 17:51:26.188 IST</ValueDate>
      <Remarks>abc</Remarks>
    </com.jms.InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
    <com.rbsfm.ice.ioa.jms.InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
      <InvoiceReference343>SM/4315</InvoiceReference>
      <RBSReference>I157311</RBSReference>
      <Currency>EUR</Currency>
      <InvoiceAmount>2554546.0</InvoiceAmount>
      <PaidAmount>12543545.0</PaidAmount>
      <BalanceAmount>0.0</BalanceAmount>
      <ValueDate>2015-05-21 17:51:26.188 IST</ValueDate>
      <Remarks>abERRc</Remarks>
    </com.jms.InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
  </invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
</brokermail>
```

Which is not correct as I am looking for the below one should come please advise how to achieve this.

```xml
<brokermail>
  <invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
    <InvoiceReference>AA/54545829709/0315</InvoiceReference>
    <RBSReference>IRMA4545R157311</RBSReference>
    <Currency>GBP</Currency>
    <InvoiceAmount>255446.0</InvoiceAmount>
    <PaidAmount>124545.0</PaidAmount>
    <BalanceAmount>0.0</BalanceAmount>
    <ValueDate>2015-05-20 21:34:34.165 IST</ValueDate>
    <Remarks>abc</Remarks>
  </invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
   <invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
    <InvoiceReference>xx/8245459709/0315</InvoiceReference>
    <RBSReference>IRMAR545157311</RBSReference>
    <Currency>GBP</Currency>
    <InvoiceAmount>2545456.0</InvoiceAmount>
    <PaidAmount>124455.0</PaidAmount>
    <BalanceAmount>0.0</BalanceAmount>
    <ValueDate>2015-05-20 21:34:34.165 IST</ValueDate>
    <Remarks>abc</Remarks>
  </invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
</brokermail>
```

As you can see the below tag is

```xml
<com.jms.InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
```

is extra which I do not require, please advise me on how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
    private  List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage = 
new ArrayList<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>();
```

to:

```
    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage")
    private  List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage = 
new ArrayList<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>();
```

and add:

```
xstream.processAnnotations(Mail.class);
```

Comment: it is showing me compliation error for annotation XStreamImplicit , in eclipse editor it is advising to create the annotation  XStreamImplicit , please advise how to proceed

Comment: Do you have all the required XStream jars in your buildpath? Do you Import the XStreamImplicit annotation in your class? Like this: import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamImplicit;

Comment: i have added this import import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

Comment: Add this: import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamImplicit; to you mail class

Comment: using xstream 1.1.3 jar

Comment: Use newest XStream https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/groups/public/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/